# в бд приходят пустые ячейки

Tags: php, html, база-данных

**пытаюсь передать переменные из формы и из js в php , пишет что данные переданы а в базе данных просто пустые ячейки**

отрывок из index.html

```
<form action="rezultat.php" method="get">
    <h3>Имя:</h3>
    <input  name="name">
     <input  name="prize" id="mytext">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

rezultat.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $prize= $_POST['prize'];
    // Параметры для подключения
    $db_host = "XXXX"; 
    $db_user = "XXXX"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = "XXXX"; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = "XXXX"; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "XXXX"; // Имя Таблицы БД
    
    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_base);

if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
echo "Connected successfully";
 
$sql =  "INSERT INTO tablica(name,prize) VALUES ('$name','$prize')";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
    if($result)
    {
        
        echo "<span style='color:blue;'>Данные добавлены</span>";
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: попробуйте в форме изменить на method="post", а не get

Comment: та же пустая строка приходит...

Comment: var_dump($_POST) выводит информацию?

Comment: `VALUES ('$name','$prize')` тут я бы заменил одиночные кавычки на тильды `VALUES (\`$name\`,\`$prize\`)`

Comment: сейчас проверю var_dump . кавычки тоже попробую сменить

Comment: var_dump просто крашает , с тильдами логи пишут что переменные ожидались а нифига не пришло

Comment: а хотя нет , дамп показал что null от формы передается

Comment: что с этим можно сделать ?